# Looping a command over a list of arguments in Linux

Tags: linux, pipe

How to execute the same command with arguments that are delivered by another command via pipe?

As a result of the extraction of file names from a source I get:

```
    $some_command
    filename1
    filename2
    filename3
    ...
    filenameN
```

I'd like to create files with these filenames with `touch`. How can I loop `touch` over these names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I only use for ... do ... done for very simple cases.

For more complicated/dangerous scenarios:

```
command | sed 's/^/touch /'
```

This does nothing but prints intended commands. Review the results, then perform the same thing piping to `sh -x` (the `-x` flag is for debugging):

```
command | sed 's/^/touch /' | sh -x
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use xargs with -n1 to run a command once for each piped argument

```
$some_command | xargs -n 1 touch
```

---

In the case of touch however which accepts multiple arguments

```
touch `$some_command`
```

will probably work for you.

Comment: theotherreceive is correct, you can also use $some_command | xargs -I {} touch -option {}    .This is helpful when you need to use options on your xarg execution.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in `$some_command`; do touch $i; done
```

Comment: ...and hope none of the filenames have whitespace.

Comment: Put double quotes around $i to take care of spaces.

Comment: Not quite mr. Bash. First of all, he has to set the IFS variable and later remember to restore it to old value.

Answer (score 2):

If the filenames contain whitespace, then the following will work around them:

```
some_command | while read filename ; do touch "$filename" ; done
```

This will create files named:
file name 1
file name 2
named file 3
etc

Assuming, of course, that it does produce those names.

Comment: It will NOT work with whitespace... You need touch "$filename".

Answer (score 1):

"some_command | xargs touch" will probably do the trick, however there are two pitfalls:

1. If a filename contains any whitespace character it will be treated as a separator, for example a filename "fuh bar" will, this way, be "touch"ed as a file named "fuh" and another one named "bar" instead of a single "fuh bar" one. To alleviate this you may check if your "some_command" is able to produce another delimiter, often NULL (see the "-print0" argument legit with the command "find"), and use the "--null" argument of xargs
2. If the command does not produce anything xargs will fail miserably. Use its "--no-run-if-empty" argument